# Why have we made a function to be many to one and not one to many?

Tags: calculus, functions

We have allowed function to only relate many to one but not one to many. Why haven't we included sin(x) to be a function? Is it just for simplicity? Also, I've seen someone quote a function not even being many to one, but being explicitly one to one. Why have we defined functions to be like this?

Comment: $\sin$ is a function.

Comment: Do you mean by one to many and many to one injective and surjective properties? In any case, $sin$ is a function, and it gives, from "many" different inputs, the same results...

Comment: Could a function not be made one to many? For example, $f: X \rightarrow Y$ could be made into $f: X \rightarrow \wp(Y)$? Now just map your element onto the  subset of $Y$ you wanted to map it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we had a "one to many" "function". Then that would have to imply that $f(x)$ could be anything from some (possibly infinite) set of possible values $\{ y_1, y_2, \cdots \}$. This is a problem, since we then have:

$$x = y ~ ~ \text{need not imply} ~ ~ f(x) = f(y)$$

And how would you even **choose** what $f(x)$ should be, based solely on $x$? There are two solutions:

- Add some more state $s$ to the "function" $f$ which determines what $x$ should be sent to, but then at this point you have a normal many to one (or one to one) function $f_s$ and are back to square one
- Accept that the application of $f$ is nondeterministic, at which point most of the properties of calculus and math in general that you take for granted simply fly out the window (want to solve an equation? tough luck, applying *the same "function"* to both sides need not preserve the equation!)

So that settles the problem of why we can't expect one to many "functions" to behave the same as what is called a function in mathematics (even in principle). This is not to say such objects are necessarily useless - perhaps they have been studied. But they are not called functions, because they behave very differently.

---

Now, it is possible that by "one to many" you mean "sends a value to a set of values" (as opposed to one of a set of values as previously - note the difference). This is perfectly valid, and that function is in fact not one to many, as it still sends each value to *one* particular set of values. Not convinced? How about the function $f$ which, given a positive integer $n$, returns the set of positive multiples of $n$? We have:

$$f(1) = \{ 1, 2, 3, \cdots \}$$
$$f(2) = \{ 2, 4, 6, \cdots \}$$
$$f(3) = \{ 3, 6, 9, \cdots \}$$

Notice that each of the sets on the right-hand-side can be thought of as a single object, and there is no problem determining which set $n$ should be sent to, for any integer $n \geq 1$. We get:

$$f(n) = \{ n, 2n, 3n, \cdots \}$$

And $f$ is, indeed, a function. It also happens to be one-to-one, as it never sends two integers to the same set, *even though* individual sets might share values, e.g. $f(1)$ contains $2$, but so does $f(2)$. Think about that. Functions don't need to send numbers to numbers, they can be made much more general.

---

Finally, $\sin$ is in fact a function. Who told you otherwise? It is clearly many to one as it is periodic but it is not "one to many" as $\sin$ always maps an input $x$ to a single value $\sin(x)$ (the sine of $x$).

And a function in the general sense need not be one-to-one, it can be many-to-one (as $\sin$ just above is). But depending on the context, people might need to work exclusively with one-to-one functions because of their properties, and so will tend shorten that to "function" for brevity (you will usually see something like "let $f$ be a one-to-one function... the function... this function..." or "we will refer to one-to-one functions as functions from here on").

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i like your very detailed way of explaining. I did think sine was a function but then i read somewhere that it couldn't be, which prompted to ask this question in frustration.